# How to recolor Shapes/Lines

Tags: vba, visio

I have Shapes/Lines I need to recolor.

The problem I encounter is I can't just highlight everything and change line color, or Text Shapes that have no line color will then also now have lines.

How can I either take 2 reference variables for the select color and the recolor, or have the select color based off a currently selected object.

I want to recolor everything from Green to Black.

This is what I hashed together from other guides on the web. It selects objects without lines still (not a lot but some) and won't target anything that's within a group.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActivePage.Shapes
      If s.Cells("LineColor").ResultStr(0) = "RGB(0, 176, 80)" Then
        ActiveWindow.Select s, visSelect
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveWindow.Select s, visSelect

This line just select shape, not change its color, try use this line

```
s.Cells("LineColor").FormulaU = "0"
```

If you need change shapes into group you must use [recursive algorithm](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=7286.msg30645;topicseen#msg30645)